# htaccess remove param name from url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to remove the get keys from my URL.

So `https://www.website.com/?page=gallery` would become `https://www.website.com/gallery`.

And if `&action` is there it should be like
`https://www.website.com/?page=gallery&action=view` into `https://www.website.com/gallery/view`.

Of course, `gallery`, and `view` are dynamic - they define what page my site loads.

I have been trying all day, but to no avail. Can any of you help me out here?

My current `.htaccess`:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from <MYIP>

ErrorDocument 403 /message.html

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Hide index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]


#Force www and https:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip

Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following a try (just above your gzip section):

```
# Step 1: Redirect query-based URL to new one

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&\s]+)$
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php|)$ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&\s]+)&action=([^&\s]+)$
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php|)$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# Step 2: Rewrite new URIs to query-based one
#
# Note how a dummy &r is used in the destination - this is
# to prevent infinite loops

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\s\/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&r [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\s\/]+)/([^\s\/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2&r [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you man, this worked. :)  Just one last part that may need fixing is the &action=  it loads page?page=page&action=ACTION.  However it works almost perfectly!  this stuff is confusing, but I really like it.  Any ideas on what to do next?

Comment: You're welcome. It shouldn't be doing that at all, because of the question mark after `%2`, which cancels the query string. Perhaps try clearing your cache?

Comment: Perhaps you could try using the [query string discard flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) instead of the question marks after `%2`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the QUERY_STRING condition - perhaps something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)&action=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/%2/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but based on what you're asking something like this should get you there?:

```
RewriteEngine on
# to convert from folders request query string index handler
RewriteRule ^/([^/\.]+)(/([^/\.]+))/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$3 [L]
# or reverse from query string to folder paths (more limited/confining) 
RewriteRule ^/?(page=([^&]+)(&action=([^&]+)(&?(.*))$ /$2/$4?$6 [L]
```

Comment: `mod_rewrite` doesn't support query strings in rules. Please read the documentation before posting answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this below the force www rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(?:index\.php|)\?page=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is working the most so far. https://www.website.com/gallery/?page=gallery is the result

Comment: @AustinWilley you sure you added the `?` at the end of the rule's target?